Using google sheets query functions to filter a list for unique values
I am trying to organize an inventory sheet but need some advice. I have a webhook sending data in regularly. The sheet is below. In the source database, I will update different data fields and then the webhook sends the record (including any changes) along with a timestamp.
I'm trying to return the full row, for only the most recent entry (based on timestamp_incoming_webhook) and filtered for duplicates based on data_inventory_item_serial_number. I am struggling to do this with the query function in a single (or a series of) command(s).
For example, I can do
=query(FilterToAntibodyFlow!A:I, "select A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I,max(C) WHERE B <> '' group by A,B,D,E,F,G,H,I label max(C)'timestamp_incoming_webhook'",1)

but this no longer properly filter for duplicates in the column B (data_inventory_item_serial_number). For example, rows 5 and 6 are duplicates.

But if I only do group by B then the filtering is accurate but I don't get back the other columns of data. How can I get the full record for the most recently changed version?

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you know that Google Sheets has UNIQUE function? If you need further help add sample data as text instead as an image.

It would be helpful if you showed a sample of your raw data and a sample of your expected result rather than what you "don't" want.


You may try:
=let(Σ,reduce(FilterToAntibodyFlow!A1:I1,unique(tocol(FilterToAntibodyFlow!B2:B,1)),lambda(a,c,vstack(a,chooserows(sort(filter(FilterToAntibodyFlow!A:I,FilterToAntibodyFlow!B:B=c),3,),1)))),
 choosecols(Σ,1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,3))



I'm not entirely clear from your description if you are trying to filter the rows of data by newest to oldest and then remove duplicate rows based on column B or something different. An example of your desired result would go a long way to provide clarity.
If it is the former, a combination of SORT and SORTN would do the trick:
=LET(range, FilterToAntibodyFlow!A:I,
   SORTN(
     SORT(range,3,0), 
     ROWS(range), 2, 2, 1)) 


LET stores the range reference in range for reuse.
range is sorted by date in descending order (newest to oldest).
SORTN then sorts the range by column B (2), removing any duplicates.
Because of the earlier sort by date descending, discarded duplicates will be older than the row that is kept.

SORT    SORTN
